# symfony 4.1 phpunit 6.5 show catched exceptions on console using WebTestCase

Tags: symfony, phpunit, symfony4

I use **Symfony 4.1 WebTestCase** and phpunit 6.5 for test that an not-existing user can not log **using Symfony Authentification against database**.

I think **phpunit should NOT show any errors**, but it writes in console many **exceptions**, as the output is plenty of non important **exceptions** as they **have been catched correctly**.

Also, **assertNotEquals** throws a compare exception too !!

Please if anybody can explain me how to fix it.I have been for days without any luck.

My code is like this (Sorry, My first question on this web):

```
//------------------ REQUEST FOR PAGE LOGIN
$crawler = $client->request('GET', $url_login);

//------------------ (SOM NOT IMPORTANT STAFF AND REDIRECTION)
$crawler = $client->submit($form);

//------------------ SENDING INCORRECT LOGIN USER
$form = $crawler->filter('.btn.btn-primary.btn-block')->form();
// set some values
$form['_username'] = 'failed_user';
$form['_password'] = 'failed_password';

//------------------ ALL IS OK SINCE HERE


//------------------ THIS SHOWS 
//UsernameNotFoundException ON CONSOLE BUT EXCEPTION HAS BEEN CATCHED 
//AND FORM RETURNED OK SAYING "This user doesn't exist"

$crawler = $client->submit($form);

//------------------ THIS SHOW 
// SebastianBergmann\Comparator\ComparisonFailure:  Failed asserting that two strings are equal...
//ON CONSOLE !!

$this->assertNotEquals($url_login, $url_resp, 'La página de login no es la esperada al identificarnos correctamente');
```

And console is like this:

```
esteban@linux-9j0e:~/workspace_newproject/mywebproject> bin/phpunit 
#!/usr/bin/env php
PHPUnit 6.5.11 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Testing Project Test Suite
PHP Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException:  User "esteban_fail" not found. in /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/doctrine-bridge/Security/User/EntityUserProvider.php on line 61
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. require() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/phpunit:18
PHP   3. include() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/phpunit-bridge/bin/simple-phpunit:260
PHP   4. PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/phpunit:17
PHP   5. Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\Legacy\CommandForV6->run() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/TextUI/Command.php:148
PHP   6. Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\Legacy\TestRunnerForV6->doRun() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/TextUI/Command.php:195
PHP   7. PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->run() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php:546
PHP   8. PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->run() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/TestSuite.php:755
PHP   9. App\Tests\Controller\Security\Login\LoginControllerTest->run() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/TestSuite.php:755
PHP  10. PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult->run() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/TestCase.php:894
PHP  11. App\Tests\Controller\Security\Login\LoginControllerTest->runBare() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/TestResult.php:698
PHP  12. App\Tests\Controller\Security\Login\LoginControllerTest->runTest() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/TestCase.php:939
PHP  13. ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/TestCase.php:1071
PHP  14. App\Tests\Controller\Security\Login\LoginControllerTest->testshowLoginFails() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/TestCase.php:1071
PHP  15. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client->submit() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/tests/Controller/Security/Login/LoginControllerTest.php:96
PHP  16. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client->request() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/browser-kit/Client.php:298
PHP  17. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client->doRequest() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/browser-kit/Client.php:351
PHP  18. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client->doRequest() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Client.php:131
PHP  19. App\Kernel->handle() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Client.php:68
PHP  20. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:188
PHP  21. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:66
PHP  22. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:125
PHP  23. Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php:141
PHP  24. Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:44
PHP  25. Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener->__invoke() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:212
PHP  26. call_user_func:{/home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php:104}() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php:104
PHP  27. Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Debug\TraceableFirewallListener->onKernelRequest() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php:104
PHP  28. Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Debug\TraceableFirewallListener->onKernelRequest() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/security-bundle/EventListener/FirewallListener.php:48
PHP  29. Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Debug\TraceableFirewallListener->handleRequest() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/security/Http/Firewall.php:61
PHP  30. Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Debug\WrappedListener->handle() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/security-bundle/Debug/TraceableFirewallListener.php:35
PHP  31. Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener->handle() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/security-bundle/Debug/WrappedListener.php:46
PHP  32. Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener->attemptAuthentication() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/security/Http/Firewall/AbstractAuthenticationListener.php:128
PHP  33. Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\AuthenticationProviderManager->authenticate() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/security/Http/Firewall/UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener.php:100
PHP  34. Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\DaoAuthenticationProvider->authenticate() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/security/Core/Authentication/AuthenticationProviderManager.php:76
PHP  35. Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\DaoAuthenticationProvider->retrieveUser() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/security/Core/Authentication/Provider/UserAuthenticationProvider.php:64
PHP  36. Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\EntityUserProvider->loadUserByUsername() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/security/Core/Authentication/Provider/DaoAuthenticationProvider.php:74
PHP Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException:  User "esteban_fail" not found. in /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/doctrine-bridge/Security/User/EntityUserProvider.php on line 61
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. require() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/phpunit:18
PHP   3. include() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/phpunit-bridge/bin/simple-phpunit:260
PHP   4. PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/phpunit:17
PHP   5. Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\Legacy\CommandForV6->run() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/TextUI/Command.php:148
PHP   6. Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\Legacy\TestRunnerForV6->doRun() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/TextUI/Command.php:195
PHP   7. PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->run() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php:546
PHP   8. PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->run() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/TestSuite.php:755
PHP   9. App\Tests\Controller\Security\Login\LoginControllerTest->run() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/TestSuite.php:755
PHP  10. PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult->run() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/TestCase.php:894
PHP  11. App\Tests\Controller\Security\Login\LoginControllerTest->runBare() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/TestResult.php:698
PHP  12. App\Tests\Controller\Security\Login\LoginControllerTest->runTest() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/TestCase.php:939
PHP  13. ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/TestCase.php:1071
PHP  14. App\Tests\Controller\Security\Login\LoginControllerTest->testshowLoginFails() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/TestCase.php:1071
PHP  15. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client->submit() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/tests/Controller/Security/Login/LoginControllerTest.php:96
PHP  16. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client->request() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/browser-kit/Client.php:298
PHP  17. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client->doRequest() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/browser-kit/Client.php:351
PHP  18. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client->doRequest() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Client.php:131
PHP  19. App\Kernel->handle() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Client.php:68
PHP  20. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:188
PHP  21. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:66
PHP  22. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:125
PHP  23. Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php:141
PHP  24. Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:44
PHP  25. Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener->__invoke() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:212
PHP  26. call_user_func:{/home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php:104}() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php:104
PHP  27. Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Debug\TraceableFirewallListener->onKernelRequest() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php:104
PHP  28. Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Debug\TraceableFirewallListener->onKernelRequest() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/security-bundle/EventListener/FirewallListener.php:48
PHP  29. Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Debug\TraceableFirewallListener->handleRequest() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/security/Http/Firewall.php:61
PHP  30. Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Debug\WrappedListener->handle() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/security-bundle/Debug/TraceableFirewallListener.php:35
PHP  31. Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener->handle() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/security-bundle/Debug/WrappedListener.php:46
PHP  32. Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener->attemptAuthentication() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/security/Http/Firewall/AbstractAuthenticationListener.php:128
PHP  33. Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\AuthenticationProviderManager->authenticate() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/security/Http/Firewall/UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener.php:100
PHP  34. Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\DaoAuthenticationProvider->authenticate() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/security/Core/Authentication/AuthenticationProviderManager.php:76
PHP  35. Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\DaoAuthenticationProvider->retrieveUser() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/security/Core/Authentication/Provider/UserAuthenticationProvider.php:64
PHP Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException:  Bad credentials. in /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/security/Core/Authentication/Provider/UserAuthenticationProvider.php on line 67
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. require() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/phpunit:18
PHP   3. include() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/phpunit-bridge/bin/simple-phpunit:260
PHP   4. PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/phpunit:17
PHP   5. Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\Legacy\CommandForV6->run() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/TextUI/Command.php:148
PHP   6. Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\Legacy\TestRunnerForV6->doRun() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/TextUI/Command.php:195
PHP   7. PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->run() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php:546
PHP   8. PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->run() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/TestSuite.php:755
PHP   9. App\Tests\Controller\Security\Login\LoginControllerTest->run() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/TestSuite.php:755
PHP  10. PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult->run() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/TestCase.php:894
PHP  11. App\Tests\Controller\Security\Login\LoginControllerTest->runBare() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/TestResult.php:698
PHP  12. App\Tests\Controller\Security\Login\LoginControllerTest->runTest() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/TestCase.php:939
PHP  13. ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/TestCase.php:1071
PHP  14. App\Tests\Controller\Security\Login\LoginControllerTest->testshowLoginFails() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/TestCase.php:1071
PHP  15. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client->submit() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/tests/Controller/Security/Login/LoginControllerTest.php:96
PHP  16. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client->request() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/browser-kit/Client.php:298
PHP  17. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client->doRequest() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/browser-kit/Client.php:351
PHP  18. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client->doRequest() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Client.php:131
PHP  19. App\Kernel->handle() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Client.php:68
PHP  20. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:188
PHP  21. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:66
PHP  22. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:125
PHP  23. Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php:141
PHP  24. Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:44
PHP  25. Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener->__invoke() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:212
PHP  26. call_user_func:{/home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php:104}() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php:104
PHP  27. Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Debug\TraceableFirewallListener->onKernelRequest() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php:104
PHP  28. Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Debug\TraceableFirewallListener->onKernelRequest() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/security-bundle/EventListener/FirewallListener.php:48
PHP  29. Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Debug\TraceableFirewallListener->handleRequest() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/security/Http/Firewall.php:61
PHP  30. Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Debug\WrappedListener->handle() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/security-bundle/Debug/TraceableFirewallListener.php:35
PHP  31. Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener->handle() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/security-bundle/Debug/WrappedListener.php:46
PHP  32. Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener->attemptAuthentication() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/security/Http/Firewall/AbstractAuthenticationListener.php:128
PHP  33. Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\AuthenticationProviderManager->authenticate() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/security/Http/Firewall/UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener.php:100
PHP  34. Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\DaoAuthenticationProvider->authenticate() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/security/Core/Authentication/AuthenticationProviderManager.php:76
PHP Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException:  Bad credentials. in /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/security/Core/Authentication/Provider/UserAuthenticationProvider.php on line 67
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. require() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/phpunit:18
PHP   3. include() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/phpunit-bridge/bin/simple-phpunit:260
PHP   4. PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/phpunit:17
PHP   5. Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\Legacy\CommandForV6->run() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/TextUI/Command.php:148
PHP   6. Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\Legacy\TestRunnerForV6->doRun() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/TextUI/Command.php:195
PHP   7. PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->run() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php:546
PHP   8. PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->run() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/TestSuite.php:755
PHP   9. App\Tests\Controller\Security\Login\LoginControllerTest->run() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/TestSuite.php:755
PHP  10. PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult->run() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/TestCase.php:894
PHP  11. App\Tests\Controller\Security\Login\LoginControllerTest->runBare() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/TestResult.php:698
PHP  12. App\Tests\Controller\Security\Login\LoginControllerTest->runTest() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/TestCase.php:939
PHP  13. ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/TestCase.php:1071
PHP  14. App\Tests\Controller\Security\Login\LoginControllerTest->testshowLoginFails() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/TestCase.php:1071
PHP  15. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client->submit() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/tests/Controller/Security/Login/LoginControllerTest.php:96
PHP  16. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client->request() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/browser-kit/Client.php:298
PHP  17. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client->doRequest() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/browser-kit/Client.php:351
PHP  18. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client->doRequest() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Client.php:131

(...sorry, cut by putting too long text..)

PHP  26. call_user_func:{/home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php:104}() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php:104
PHP  27. Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Debug\TraceableFirewallListener->onKernelRequest() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php:104
PHP  28. Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Debug\TraceableFirewallListener->onKernelRequest() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/security-bundle/EventListener/FirewallListener.php:48
PHP  29. Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Debug\TraceableFirewallListener->handleRequest() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/security/Http/Firewall.php:61
PHP  30. Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Debug\WrappedListener->handle() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/security-bundle/Debug/TraceableFirewallListener.php:35
PHP  31. Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener->handle() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/security-bundle/Debug/WrappedListener.php:46
PHP  32. Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener->attemptAuthentication() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/security/Http/Firewall/AbstractAuthenticationListener.php:128
PHP  33. Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\AuthenticationProviderManager->authenticate() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/security/Http/Firewall/UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener.php:100
.PHP SebastianBergmann\Comparator\ComparisonFailure:  Failed asserting that two strings are equal. in /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/vendor/sebastian/comparator/src/ScalarComparator.php on line 67
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. require() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/phpunit:18
PHP   3. include() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/vendor/symfony/phpunit-bridge/bin/simple-phpunit:260
PHP   4. PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/phpunit:17
PHP   5. Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\Legacy\CommandForV6->run() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/TextUI/Command.php:148
PHP   6. Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\Legacy\TestRunnerForV6->doRun() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/TextUI/Command.php:195
PHP   7. PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->run() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php:546
PHP   8. PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->run() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/TestSuite.php:755
PHP   9. App\Tests\Controller\Admin\Security\Enteprises\AdminEnterprisesControllerTest->run() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/TestSuite.php:755
PHP  10. PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult->run() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/TestCase.php:894
PHP  11. App\Tests\Controller\Admin\Security\Enteprises\AdminEnterprisesControllerTest->runBare() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/TestResult.php:698
PHP  12. App\Tests\Controller\Admin\Security\Enteprises\AdminEnterprisesControllerTest->runTest() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/TestCase.php:939
PHP  13. ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/TestCase.php:1071
PHP  14. App\Tests\Controller\Admin\Security\Enteprises\AdminEnterprisesControllerTest->test_Add_Edit_And_Delete_Grouper() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/TestCase.php:1071
PHP  15. App\Tests\Controller\Security\Login\LoginControllerTest->ht_return_Logged_User_Client() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/tests/Controller/Admin/Security/Enterprises/AdminEnterprisesControllerTest.php:121
PHP  16. PHPUnit\Framework\Assert::assertNotEquals() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/tests/Controller/Security/Login/LoginControllerTest.php:52
PHP  17. PHPUnit\Framework\Assert::assertThat() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/Assert.php:592
PHP  18. PHPUnit\Framework\Constraint\LogicalNot->evaluate() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/Assert.php:2116
PHP  19. PHPUnit\Framework\Constraint\IsEqual->evaluate() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/Constraint/LogicalNot.php:116
PHP  20. SebastianBergmann\Comparator\ScalarComparator->assertEquals() /home/esteban/workspace_newproject/mywebproject/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/Constraint/IsEqual.php:129
.                                                               5 / 5 (100%)

Time: 1.44 seconds, Memory: 34.00MB

OK (5 tests, 70 assertions)

Remaining deprecation notices (1)

1x: Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader is deprecated.
    1x in LoginControllerTest::testshowLoginFails from App\Tests\Controller\Security\Login
```

Comment: What do you do in your catch statement when you catch the UsernameNotFoundException or the BadCredentialsException? Do you just throw them again? 

You can also use the @ExpectedException annotation above a test to show it that you expect a certain exception to be thrown.

Comment: Thanks. I'm on holidays now por two weeks. Iwill test it when back to work. Thanks very much.

Comment: Hi. Returned from holidays :D.
I can not do anithing as the logout handler is internal from symfony, So I have no posibility of catch the exception, as if you the stack there is no own code called, all code is from vendor path.

Comment: So are you not testing your own code? You're not really supposed to write tests for code that you can't control. It defeats the purpose. Let Symfony take care of their own test code and you write tests for the code that you write. Mock anything else. So if your code uses a Symfony service, mock it and don't test it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.

I wanted to test that the login service was well configured, as the "login service" redirects correctly to my user page, or launch onAuthenticationFailure handler that returns the login page with an "error on credentilas" message, but I don't know how to catch exception and not being sended to phpunit. Sending bad credentials was the only way I know to do it.

And I'm very sorry but I don't understand how to mock a service, I have read the phpunit documentation but it is not clear to me, as I have just started with phpunit. I'm still learning about it.